# Multiple fonts in Java

Tags: java, swing, java-8

Can I use multiple fonts like css IN Java? (In Graphics2D, JLabel or if needed JTextPane)

```
.helloworld {
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

The program can be very complex. If so, please provide a short description.

I want make program use English font to display English text and use multi language font to display another text.

Comment: Please edit your question to elaborate on what you want to do. It is a little bit unclear so make sure you are asking for the correct thing.

Comment: For `JTextPane`, Yes; see [this section of the Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html).  For graphics, drawing of text is entirely under your control, so, Yes, if you're willing to put in the effort.